# how to send email using constant contact instead of sendgrid in php

Tags: php, email

I have donation and membership pages in my website. present i am using sendgrid library for sending emails after every donation. Instead of sendgrid is there any possibility to use constant contact dettails for sending emails. constant contact is mainly used for sending marketing emails to subscribers. 
Present my code is

```
require("../sendgrid-php/sendgrid-php.php");
$sendgrid = new SendGrid('venky', 'venky@123');
 $subject="Hudud Donation";
 $message="<table>
        <tr><td> Regestration ID: </td><td> : </td> <td> $creg_id</td> </tr>
        <tr><td>First Name</td><td> : </td><td>$First_Name</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Last Name</td><td> : </td><td>$Last_Name</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Email Address</td><td> : </td><td>$Email_Address</td></tr>
        <tr><td>DOB</td><td> : </td><td>$dob</td></tr>
        </table>";

$email1 = new SendGrid\Email();
$email1->addTo($Email_Address)->
setFrom('info@abc.org')->
setSubject($subject)->
setHtml($message);
$mailStatus= $sendgrid->send($email1);
```

Present it is working fine using sendgrid.  How to use constant contact instead of sendgrid. Please help me

Comment: the question is not clear. `$Email_Address` is a constant contact detail of your recipient and `info@abc.org` is a constant contact detail of you. no?

Comment: there is a donation form . in donatione form user will enter his email id. that is $Email_Address

Comment: so, again, why isn't this enough for you?

Comment: or… do you mean that you want to use your own email server instead of sendgrid? just use http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php then or any other email library. in this case your question is offtopic at stackoverflow, as it is not a programming issue, but documentation reading issue

Comment: present we are using sendgrid. but instead of sendgrid i want how to use constant contact mail server details

Comment: in http://developer.constantcontact.com/libraries/sample-code.html they given coding for how to send mail templates for subscribed users in constant contac

Comment: is it possible to integrate constant contact mail server instead of sendgrid for sending emails in normal way

Comment: it was totally unobvious that "constant contact" is a name of the service. anyway, it looks like their API is not suitable for sending individual emails. so, no, you can't do this